How to navigate to a nested route with GoRouter in Flutter Web without changing URL?
I would like to create a workflow with GoRouter in my Flutter web app without changing the URL, but I can't manage to do it. Even with using ShellRoute. My router is as following:
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _shellNavigatorKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final _router = GoRouter(navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey, routes: [
  ShellRoute(
    navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
    builder: (context, state, child) {
      return child;
    },
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
        builder: (context, state) => const ProcessesListPage(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: 'process',
            parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: const ProcessViewerPage(),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                      SlideTransition(
                          position: animation.drive(
                            Tween<Offset>(
                              begin: const Offset(1, 0),
                              end: Offset.zero,
                            ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut)),
                          ),
                          child: child),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  )
]);

and I navigate to the process route with context.go("/process");
But doing so, the url change from http://localhost:8000/ to http://localhost:8000/#/process, while I would like to keep http://localhost:8000/. I have used ShellRoute and keys but I can't manage to make it work.
I am also open to solutions without GoRouter to achieve this.

I ended up creating my own navigation system without GoRouter or any route, with an event system to decide what to display. I suppose that a router has to work with routes. The only drawback I have for now is that I miss the page transitions, but it is possible to implement them with Animations.
